# javascript double wrapping text nodes

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">Testing
    <p>Some more text inside p</p>
    <p>asdasdasdasdasde p</p>
    Test
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
getTextNodes(document.getElementById("test" ), 'strong'); 

function getTextNodes(parent, tag) 
{ 
    var textNodes = []; 
    var nodes = parent.childNodes; 
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) 
    { 
       (function(i){ 
        var node = nodes[i]; 
        if(node.nodeType === 3) 
        {    
            textNodes.push(node); 
            if(node.data.match(/[^\t\r\n ]/)) 
            { 
               var words = node.nodeValue.split(' ');

               console.log(node);
               var nWords = [];
               for(var y = 0; y < words.length; y++)
               {
                    (function(y){
                    var w = words[y];
                                        if(w.trim() == ''){return;}
                    var nNode = document.createTextNode('');
                    nNode.nodeValue +=  w + ' ';

               var bold = document.createElement(tag); 
               bold.appendChild(nNode); 
               parent.insertBefore(bold, node); 

                    })(y);

               }
               parent.removeChild(node);

            }
        } 
        else 
        { 

          getTextNodes(node, tag); 
        } 
        })(i); 
    } 
}
```

here's the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/dnjsY/48/

I'am wrapping each word separated by whitespace, but the thing is that its double wrapping some text nodes with `<strong>` tag, but not the first ones like the `"some"` word, can someone give me a hint, on whats wrong? thanks

Comment: Your HTML isn't using the `<strong>` tag.

Comment: yes, because it as added in javascript, look at the function call getTextNodes(document.getElementById("test" ), 'strong'); the second param is the name of the tag dynamically created inside the function

Comment: Can you be more clear about what it is you are looking to do and what exactly the problem is. What does "double wrapping" mean?

Comment: Why do you have an Immediately Invoked Function Expression inside of your loop?

Comment: if you look at the result of the function, you'll see that there are double wrapped tags <double>, that is the problem, just look, go on the link jsfiddle and you'll see it all

Comment: the Function Expression, its just to save the for loop index(local reference)...

Comment: Just use `let` instead of `var` to do that.

Comment: yes that can be used too, but this isn't the solution for my problem

Comment: I think you should rethink the entire code structure that you have. It is entirely unclear what your attempting to do. You have IIFEs where they are not needed and you are accessing the `data` property of elements where no such property exists. I have no idea what you are talking about when you mention a `<double>` tag. Cleaning up your code is always a good first step towards solving problems.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, but sometimes you just have to push through)), now you can see what I've meant, answer added...the problem was in the js code..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dnjsY/59/ - solution

```
getTextNodes(document.getElementById("test" ), 'strong'); 

function getTextNodes(parent, tag) 
{ 
    var nodes = parent.childNodes; 
    for(let i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) 
    {

        var node = nodes[i]; 
        if(node.nodeType === 3) 
        {

            if(node.data.match(/[^\t\r\n ]/)) 
            { 
               var words = node.nodeValue.split(' ');
               var stop = false;
               var nWords = [];
               for(let y = 0; y < words.length; y++)
               {

                    var w = words[y];
                                        if(w.trim() == ''){continue;}
                    var nNode = document.createTextNode('');
                    nNode.nodeValue =  w + ' ';
               var bold = document.createElement(tag); 
              bold.innerHTML = w + ' ';

               parent.insertBefore(bold, node); 
                  if(y == 1 && i == 0)
                  {
                    stop = true;
                  }
               }

               parent.removeChild(node); 
               if(stop)
               {
                  return;

               }
            }
        } 
        else 
        { 
          getTextNodes(node, tag); 
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Where you have if(w.trim() == ''){return;, did you mean continue?".